# Lead guitarist in Hotel California?

Tags: eagles

Both Don Felder and Joe Walsh are credited as "lead guitarist" in the Eagle's song, Hotel California. Who played the long guitar solo at the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a professional video of the Eagles playing it live, clearly showing Felder's part, Walsh's part, and the numerous duet-parallel harmony licks. I have no reason to believe the studio recording was much different.

https://youtu.be/KstDSCOkkOM

The technique of two guitarists playing the same melody a third or a fourth apart (creating a parallel harmony) is an idea that many bands have exploited: not only the Eagles but before them the Allman Brothers, Status Quo, Wishbone Ash, Thin Lizzy, Judas Priest, Iron Maiden, and others. Ritchie Blackmore of Deep Purple, Brian May of Queen, and Randy Rhodes of Ozzy Osbourne's Blizzard of Oz would create this effect by overdubbing themselves in the studio; however this left them unable to recreate those parts live since each of these bands had one lone guitarist. The Eagles, with three guitarists, could record this way and perform this way live.

Comment: I see, first Felder plays, then Walsh, then they reprise the main theme together in perfect unison. That is very cool, amazing composition.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California), both play in that section.  At least to my ear it sounds like the soloist changes at 4:08.

About a minute later some harmony parts come in which could be one guitar playing chords, but which could also be two guitarists playing in close harmony.  At the end there's clearly another guitar part added in, although it's much softer, and arguably isn't a "lead" part.